# Do size mods take the place of racial mods?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

My friend made me an Ent race and it is a large creature. If he gave it racial ability score mods would those add to the +16 to strength, +8 to con, and -4 to dex from size?

Comment: Tell me he has a raccoon animal companion.

Comment: Should add the Homebrew Tag since Treants in Pathfinder are huge size, not large.

Answer (score 7):

### Ability score adjustments due to a change in size category occur only when the creature *changes* size

When a creature increases or decreases its current size category *via* magic or advancing Hit Dice or another method, *that* is when the modifiers to the creature's statistics from the [Creature Size table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) apply, unless the method's description says otherwise or provides different modifiers (and many do).

Otherwise, for example, the DM would have to adjust the statistics of every [storm giant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/giant-true/giant-storm) to account for the creature's Huge size.